# No bean name is defined when run liferay portlet

Tags: exception, service, liferay-6

I am developing portlet, There are two portlet, one is manageorganization and another is employee. I am using service of employee on manageorganization and vice varsa. There is no problem while using methods of employee service using service.jar file of employee. But Now I am facing one problem is that Any method of manageorganization which are defined on localserviceimpl using localserviceutil.

```
  Error: com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com.lftechnology.serviceexampledemo.service.SmallBusinessLocalService' is defined
12:20:22,161 ERROR [ManageOrganizationController:46] Error while using method of serviceutil.
```

Code on my controller:

```
List<SmallBusiness> listOfSb = SmallBusinessLocalServiceUtil.getListofSB();
```

I went through a couple of blogs on google, but can't find the solution. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using ANT for deployment, you can create new portlet just of service only. Then add its dependency in your portlet that requires services. You can dependency in liferay-plugin-package.properties, required-deployment-contexts=XYZ-Services-portlet. Your service will be available to all portlet having this dependency defined

Comment: I am using maven for deployment. @PriteshShah

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Any of you got solution to this ? I am stuck with same issue. Please share if it worked for you. Thank you.